# Creating HDF5 from multiple panda data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pickle, hdf5

I have 100 panda dataframes stored in .pkl files in a directory on my computer. I want to go through all dataframes and save them all in 1 HDF5 file. I was planning on saving all dataframes in 1 pickle file, but I heard HDF5 is significantly better and faster.

First I was doing this:

```
path = '/Users/srayan/Desktop/data/Pickle'
df = pd.DataFrame()
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.pkl')):
    newDF = pd.read_pickle(filename)
    df = df.append(newDF)
df.to_pickle('/Users/srayan/Desktop/data/Pickle/Merged.pkl')
```

But the longest part was converting the huge dataframe into a pickle. Any way to put this large data frame into a HDF5 or any better advice of how to converge all pickle files into 1 dataframe which can be saved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An HDF5 file is like its own filesystem internally, and you can store as many things inside it as you like.  For example:

```
for filename in glob.glob('*.pkl'):
    df = pd.read_pickle(filename)
    key = os.path.basename(filename) # or choose another name
    df.to_hdf('merged.h5', key)
```

This will store all the DataFrames into a single HDF5 file.  You can either use the old filenames as the keys in the new file, or choose some other naming convention.

If you prefer the data to be concatenated into a single dataset stored in HDF5:

```
dfs = []
for filename in glob.glob('*.pkl'):
    dfs.append(pd.read_pickle(filename))

df = pd.concat(dfs)
key = 'all_the_things'
df.to_hdf('merged.h5', key)
```

I usually enable compression within HDF5.  This doesn't make the file any harder to read, and can save a lot of disk space:

```
df.to_hdf('merged.h5', key, complib='zlib', complevel=5)
```

Comment: Sorry for potential hijacking, but how would you read the h5 file you created with pandas?

Comment: @Stian: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_hdf.html but if you want to read it in non-Python environments there are better ways to write it in the first place (Pandas' default HDF5 output format is pretty strange and not easy to use in e.g. R).

Comment: @JohnZwinck thank you so much John. Question - for the first method to store all the DataFrames into a single HDF5 file, if there are several different keys created, how do you read the HDF5 that contains all data frames? I am having trouble converting the HDF5 to a data frame since I'm unsure which key to use. Thanks!

Comment: @ShabinaRayan: You should post a new question if you're stuck on that.